# click event happening on all divs instead of one at a time - Angular5

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular5

I am very new to working with angular and have come across an issue! I have made a click event on an faq page that I am making in angular 5. The problem I am having is that when i click on one faq they all open up, instead of just the targeted one.

This is my ts:

```
public show_content = true;
  showContent () {
    this.show_content = !this.show_content;
  }
```

and my html:

```
<h4 class="accordion-toggle" (click)="showContent()">When is the app ready for download?</h4>
      <hr>
            <div class="accordion-content" *ngIf="!show_content">
                <p>
                    Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.
                </p>
            </div>
      <h4 class="accordion-toggle" (click)="showContent()">When is the app ready for download?</h4>
      <hr>
            <div class="accordion-content" *ngIf="!show_content">
                <p>
                    Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.
                </p>
            </div>
```

I understand that I am using the same *ngIf on both which is why this is happening. The question I am asking is: is there a way to do this without creating multiple variables for each faq? I get that creating a new function like so:

```
showContent2 () {
    this.show_content2 = !this.show_content2;

  }
```

and then having this in my html:

```
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle" (click)="showContent2()">When is the app ready for download?</h4>
      <hr>
            <div class="accordion-content" *ngIf="!show_content2">
```

this does do the trick however I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this as this does seem very long winded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, you could start by refactoring each faq into a faq component. That way you can isolate each one

in /src/app/my-faq/my-faq.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-faq',
  templateUrl: './my-faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-faq.component.scss']
})
export class MyFaqComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() content: string;
  show_content = false;

  constructor() {}

  showContent() {
    this.show_content = !this.show_content;
  }
}
```

in /src/app/my-faq/my-faq.component.html:

```
<h4 class="accordion-toggle" (click)="showContent()">{{ title }}</h4> 
<hr>
<div class="accordion-content" *ngIf="!show_content">
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
</div>
```

in /src/app/my-faq/my-faq.component.scss

```
.accordion-toggle {
  // your css here
}
.accordion-content {
  // your css here
}
```

in /src/app/app.module.ts add:

```
...
import { MyFaqComponent } from './my-faq/my-faq.component.ts'
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    MyFaqComponent
  ]
...
```

After declaring the component in your app, in your html, now you can just do:

```
<my-faq [title]="'When is the app ready for download?" [content]="'Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.'"></my-faq>
<my-faq [title]="'When is the app ready for download?" [content]="'Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.'"></my-faq>
```

Comment: Do you mean a totally new component for each faq? or just one template? (sorry very new to this)

Comment: No worries! Nope. I mean just a single reusable component. I added a use case for your example.

Comment: How do i import that new component into my current one?

Comment: I was assuming you had a app module file (typically app.module.ts). In there, you could declare the new my-faq component, and it'd by available everywhere else in your app and useable in other components' templates without having to import anything.

Comment: ah yes of course! so that works, the only thing not working now is that my classes no longer work? any ideas?

Comment: hmm, can you clarify the error? Which classes do you mean?

Comment: "accordion-toggle" and "accordion-content" no longer have the styling I had set for them

Comment: Edited. When componentizing, your css rules are encapsulated within each component, so a typical way is to define each component's stylings like so.